# Excel: identify the column with a specific value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file with a table of the following format, there are about 50 columns

```
A B C D E id
1 0 0 0 0  1
0 1 0 0 0  2
0 0 0 0 1  3
```

It is guaranteed that one row will have exactly 1 value which is '1', others will all be 0's

How can I transform the above to a format:

```
val  id
 A    1
 B    2
 E    3
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last val be E, not D?

Comment: @XORLX typo.. fixed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the table as you give it is in A1:F4 (with headers in row 1), first enter this formula in H1:

=SUM(A2:E4)

Then enter this **array formula**** in I1:

=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$H$1,"",INDEX($A$1:$E$1,SMALL(IF($A$2:$E$4,COLUMN($A$2:$E$4)-MIN(COLUMN($A$2:$E$4))+1),ROWS($1:1))))

Copy this formula down (though not the one in H1 - that's a one-off) until you start to get blanks for the results.

*The initial IF clause is designed such that, in rows to which the formula is copied beyond the expected number of returns (given by the formula in H1), a blank is returned. This works since ROWS($1:1) (which is equal to 1), when copied down becomes, successively, ROWS($1:2) (=2), ROWS($1:3) (=3), etc., etc.*

*The IF construction within the SMALL function generates an array of values consisting of the relative column numbers for all cases where there is a 1 somewhere in that column. The SMALL function, which has as its k parameter the ROWS($1:1) construction as above, returns, on successive rows, the 1st such value, then the 2nd such value, etc., etc.*

*These column indices are then passed to INDEX to give the corresponding entry from the headers.*

Then enter this (non-array) formula in J1:

=IF(I1="","",INDEX($F$2:$F$4,MATCH(1,INDEX($A$2:$E$4,,MATCH(I1,$A$1:$E$1,0)),0)))

Copy down as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put in a line describing what these formulas do? Or are they too complex to be described in 1-2 lines?

Comment: Of course. I'll add some lines of explanation shortly.

Comment: Actually, before I do so, I just realise that I may have made this unnecessarily complex. Can the formula in H1 be replaced with simply: =SUM(A2:E4)?

Comment: It does give the correct result

Comment: Ok. I've put that formula in the post instead. What sort of explanation do you want? A detailed breakdown (which could be quite lengthy)? Or just the gist of what each part does?

Comment: A gist would be good :)  I should be able to look up the details myself after that

Comment: Added an explanation for the first array formula. Do you require one for the second, non-array formula?